# How to initialize a null table in dolphindb?

Tags: unit-testing, types, null, initialization, dolphindb

I want to write a test case about null table in dolphindb. But there in the manual ,I can only find how to initialize an int(float/temporal scalar) or a vector....Therefore, how to initialize a null table in dolphindb?

Answer (score 0):

Please use function `table` to create a null table

```
colNames =`id`value
colTypes =[INT, DOUBLE]
capacity = 1000
size = 10
t = table(capacity : size, colNames, colTypes)
```